# ¿Es posible agregar separador de miles en R a nivel global?

Tags: r, decimal

Sé que se puede cambiar el separador decimal para que en lugar de ser un punto sea una coma de esta manera:

```
options(OutDec=",")
```

¿Existe algún comando similar que permita agregar un punto (.) como separador de miles? En mi caso es para un flexdashboard, la idea sería que se aplique a todo el documento y no tener que estar haciendo la corrección en cada dataframe o estructura.

Gracias!

Comment: Si revisas la ayuda `?options` puedes ver todas las configuraciones globales de R, y lamentablemente no hay nada para establecer de manera general el separador de miles. Si dás un ejemplo con código tal vez podamos darte alguna alternativa más cómoda.

Comment: Ah, ya veo, gracias! Voy a agregar un ejemplo más tarde, pero básicamente es un dashboard con tablas (kable) y gráficos (plotly), y como algunos números son grandes hubiera resultado cómodo el separador de miles